# How can I access a Siteminder protected WSDL service from Tridion?

Tags: content-delivery

How can I call a Siteminder protected WSDL service from Tridion?

Has anyone tried this using Java Core Service ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Tridion?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange! I have edited your question slightly to hopefully clarify what you are asking, however I am still somewhat unsure myself. What is the use case you are trying to accomplish with accessing a Siteminder protected service?

Comment: +1 on Glenn's comment, could you perhaps edit the question and add some more detail to your question? That will make it a lot easier for us to provide a clear and valid answer.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to follow the same approach as when configuring the XPM with SiteMinder.  Basically, you configure the SSO server to exclude the web service path.  This is described here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/concept_59979CAA10334D61979C34C85FA7703A (login required).

But if you are confined to having your web service go via the SiteMinder, then I suggest following SiteMinder's documentation and standard web service proxy client documentation on how to bind via an SSO provider.